# Swift CloudKit reading when not logged in to iCloud

Tags: ios, database, swift, icloud, cloudkit

So I can read information from my database when (in the simulator) I'm logged into my iCloud, however, everyone who has my app will (obviously) not be. When I try to access database when Im not logged in, this error message appears:

```
<CKError 0x7fc1e3416510: "Request Rate Limited" (7/2008); "This operation has been rate limited"; Retry after 3.0 seconds>
```

followed by:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named com.apple.cloudd) UserInfo=0x7fc1e352f800 {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.cloudd}
```

Code:

```
//VARIABLES********************************************************

@IBOutlet var questions: UILabel!
var resultsOfDB : String = ""
var indexes : [Int] = []
var counter : Int = 0
var newStr : String = ""
//*****************************************************************

@IBAction func getNewQbutton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    var publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase


    let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "QuestionsTable", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))


    publicDB.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil){
        results, error in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        }

        else
        {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                self.resultsOfDB = results.description

                //for each character in resultsOfDB
                for character in self.resultsOfDB{

                    if(character == "\""){
                        self.indexes.append(self.counter)

                    }
                    self.counter++
                }


                self.newStr = self.resultsOfDB.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(self.resultsOfDB.startIndex, self.indexes[0] + 1), end: advance(self.resultsOfDB.endIndex, -(self.counter - self.indexes[1]))))

                self.questions.text = self.newStr
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how someone can read in my database when they aren't logged in to my iCloud account? Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Okay I did! I thought/think it might be a setup problem, meaning I incorrectly set the database wrong or something like that, so I wasn't sure if the code was needed or not!

Comment: by default read rights are set for everyone on a recordType in your public database.  A user does not have to be loged in to query those records. They do have to log in to their own iCloud account if they want to write data.

Answer (score 2):

The public database is only readable with no login in the production environment, not in the development environment.

Apple's documentation says:

> In development, when you run your app through Xcode on a simulator or a device, you need to enter iCloud credentials to read records in the public database. In production, the default permissions allow non-authenticated users to read records in the public database but do not allow them to write records.

See [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simulator bug (The Apple team is likely to fix this in the coming updates). 
If your simulator is not logged into iCloud, this error will occur.
However, this error will not occur in the virtual device even if that device does not have iCloud logged in